# mongoose is returning me an error that save() doesn't accept call backs anymore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const humanSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
})

const Human =  mongoose.model('human',humanSchema)
humanSchema.post('save',function(docs,next){
    console.log("A save function occured")
    next()
})
const h = new Human({name:"john"})
h.save(function(err){
    console.log("logged")
});
```

first, there is an error of save() not accepting callbacks and I am trynna learn how to use post()but it never logs the event.

I want the post() function to log "a save function occured"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try to define your middleware BEFORE compiling models:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#defining

```
const humanSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
})
humanSchema.post('save',function(docs,next){
    console.log("A save function occured")
    next()
})
const Human =  mongoose.model('human',humanSchema)
```

Second, if you want to run something after save() you need to chain functions with .then

```
doc.save().then(savedDoc => {
  console.log('Doc saved');
});
```

Or using async/await (maybe inside a try...catch block)

```
await doc.save();
console.log('Doc saved');
```